# How to change colour of reoccurring appt in Microsoft Outlook 2016 without changing all other appts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, colors

I have been asked to colour code appts in Microsoft Outlook in blue and then change these to green when attended or red if they different show up for the appt. To save time the appts have been set up as reoccurring appts. When I try to change the colour all appts both prior to the one I am trying to change and subsequent appts change colour. Is there any way I can just adjust the colour of the one appt without it affecting all other appts that have been set using reoccurrence function?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to change the color of a whole reoccurring meeting and don't affect other reccurring meeting series, or just change the color of a single meeting in reccurrence?

For case 1: We could directly right-click the meeting and choose the category to change the color that you need, and it actually couldn't affect other reccurring meeting series.

For case 2: Based on my research, we couldn't only change the category(color) of a single one if it's in a reccurrence series, but as an alternative, we could change the "**show as**" like below for it:

[image]

If it could also meet your need, here are the detailed steps:
double-click the one that you need to change>choose "just this one">change"show as"